# Is there a proper name for this interface pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, interface, coding-style

Let's say I have a generic interface like:

```
public interface IWorkBroker<TWork, TResult>
{

   ...

}
```

And then, for the sake of prettiness I do:

```
public interface IFooWorker : IWorkBroker<Foo, Bar>
{

    ...

}
```

Is there a name for this pattern?

Does anyone do this? (Let's assume that the "wrapping" interface is not defining any additional functionality; it's purely cosmetic.  i.e. making my composition root a little easier to visually scan through)

Thanks!

Comment: I'd call that a `typedef`, or more generally an alias.

Comment: If it would result in a significant improvement in how the code looks, you probably need to review your naming policy and/or design. I can't imagine the need for this in a well-designed project with good naming.

Comment: If you're intent on it, and working in a language that supports aliasing (e.g. C++ with `typedef` or `#define`), I'd say it definitely needs to be an alias instead.